# SQL Server Reporting Services - how does it work with AD

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, permissions, active-directory

I've set up Report Server and all is working properly. Except for one thing and I do not know if it's a feature or a bug.

In particular: is Reporting Services access governed only by internal security settings or are they overridden by AD Server?
Reason I'm asking is because Reporting Services are available for everyone in Domain Admin group, regardless if they're set up in `Security` section of the `Site Settings`.

I know it's logical and how it's supposed to work, but we have large Domain Admin group which will be difficult to cull.

So is there a way to limit access to SSRS to only authorized users, regardless of their other affiliations, up to and including AD group(s) membership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove Domain Admins from the Local Admins group on the server, or use an account other than BUILTIN\Administrators as the admin account for SSRS.

A determined Domain Admin could just log into the server and change those settings back, though. Really your problem is that you have too many Domain Admins. There isn't any way to wholly prevent Domain Admins from ever gaining access, after all, they are Domain Admins.

Comment: Removed BUILTIN\Administrators from SSRS site settings entirely, restarted SSRS and... no joy. I can still run the report by just being DomainAdmin. I've kind of expected that... AD trumps SSRS every time, it seems. That's fine - if management wants secure reporting, they need to cull the DA group anyway - not my problem. ;) Did not work but thanks regardless - it was a noble effort. Maybe next time..

Comment: No, I mean in the server's local users and group (lusrmgr.msc) - post a screenshot of what you have in there under Groups>Administrators. 

You are absolutely correct though. If your org wants security (for any application really), it has to start with appropriate AD user configuration. Taking shortcuts like this is just an illusion of security.

Comment: Oh... Sorry then, misunderstood. And you're right, there's a boatload of all types of admin groups with even more users, including Domain Admins.
That's all right though - not my department so not my problem. Someone else will be thinning the herd. ;)